# Operation with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering the following dataframe, I need the `df` dataframe to have only `id's` not in `df_inf` and `df_sup`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'name':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']})
df_inf = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3]})
df_sup = pd.DataFrame({'id': [6,7,8]})
```

Is there any proper function of pandas that operates? I'm trying in a fairly trivial way and it's not giving back:

```
df = df['id'] - (df_inf['id'] + df_sup['id'])
df
```

Comment: `df[~(df["id"].isin(df_inf["id"]) | df["id"].isin(df_sup["id"]))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter `id` as follows:

```
df = df[(~df['id'].isin(df_inf['id'])) & (~df['id'].isin(df_sup['id']))]
```